# not long polling with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Because of rack of session capacity of Load Balancer.

I'd like to no use any long polling with Socket.io.

Does anyone who knows how to short & frequent polling with Socket.io?

or other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To short-poll. you can set the polling duration of Socket.IO to something small, like one second, or zero.

```
io.set('polling duration', 1);
```

The default for a HTTP poll is 20 seconds. Setting the poll duration to one second effectively emulates short polling.